# Outlook interoperability

Tags: c#, outlook

When i declare ,

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass excel =
         new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
```

I  receive errors as

'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.

and

The type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' has no constructors defined

What is the solution?

Comment: You are using Excel in your question... not outlook.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Either use the interface:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application()
```

or disable embedding of Interop types for this assembly (References -> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook (right click) -> Properties -> Set 'Embed Interop Types' to False)

More info on the *why* can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2009/12/07/interop-type-xxx-cannot-be-embedded-use-the-applicable-interface-instead.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
var outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
```